# Cannot find either column “dbo” or the user-defined function or aggregate “dbo.replace_illegal_characters”, or the name is ambiguous

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers, user-defined-functions

I have created the following **Scalar-valued Function** in sql server:

```
CREATE FUNCTION replace_illegal_characters
(
    @str NVARCHAR(120)
)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(120)
AS
BEGIN

    Declare @pattern as varchar(20)
    Set @pattern = '%[^a-zA-Z0-9]%'
    While PatIndex(@pattern, @str) > 0
        Set @str = Stuff(@str, PatIndex(@pattern, @str), 1, '')

    Return @str

END
GO
```

and I am calling it in my **Trigger** like this:

```
SET @username = LOWER(dbo.replace_illegal_characters(@first_name)) + '.' + LOWER(@last_name);
```

but I get the following error:

> Cannot find either column “dbo” or the user-defined function or
> aggregate “dbo.replace_illegal_characters”, or the name is ambiguous

Any help would be muck appreciated :)

Comment: Are you connected to the same database as the database you created the function in?

Comment: Also, I strongly recommend changing that function to a set-based solution, not a `WHILE`. SQL performs awfully at iterative solutions, and this could be incredibly slow with a large set. If you aren't on SQL Server 2019, I also recommend changing it to an inline table-value function, rather than a Scalar Function, however, on the latest version of SQL Server you can make use of the inlining of user defined scalar functions.

Comment: I jsut noticed this statement as well *"and I am calling it in my Trigger like this: `SET @username =- ... @Firstname`"* I *could* be reading too much into it, but that has a **very strong** *code smell* of being a `TRIGGER` that assumes that a DML statement only ever effects one row (or, just as bad, iterates the rows in `inserted`/`deleted`). Certainly, however, if you are calling that function in a `TRIGGER` then you **must** fix that iteration problem; it's going to kill any performance on the table. Seerms like, to me, you have multiple underlying problems you need to fix.

Comment: I really suggest taking a step back here and posting a new question showing us the problem you are actually trying to resolve. I very much suspect that the above function is the result of an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info) and that your `TRIGGER` and `FUNCTION` are both severely flawed.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the function is create in the dbo schema. if dbo isn't the default schema for the user, the function will be create under user's default schema.

Change `CREATE FUNCTION replace_illegal_characters` by `CREATE FUNCTION dbo.replace_illegal_characters`